# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'nombre' in 'field list' ERROR?

Tags: java, mysql, insert, field

I don't know why this isn't working. I had already used the same code in another part of my program. Any help?

```
 try {
       PreparedStatement pps;
      pps = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ventas (nombre,precio,cant)
                                  VALUES (?,?,?)");
            pps.setString(1, productotxt.getText());
            pps.setString(2, preciotxt.getText());
            pps.setString(3, cantidadtxt.getText());
            pps.executeUpdate();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro exitoso!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(add.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

This is my EER Diagram if it helps.

[image: []]

Comment: You could try to enquote names with bactick: "INSERT INTO ventas (`nombre`,`precio`,`cant`)VALUES (?,?,?)"

Comment: Use backtick symbol ` around your field and table names.

Comment: Same error appears :/

Comment: Saeed, how? I mean, where do I put it?

Comment: INSERT INTO \`ventas\` (\`nombre\`,\`precio\`,\`cant\`)VALUES (?,?,?)

Comment: It didn't work :/ Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **setInt** instead of **setString** because values precio & cantidad are **int** type at you database.

```
try {
           PreparedStatement pps;
          pps = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ventas (nombre,precio,cant)VALUES (?,?,?)");
                pps.setString(1, productotxt.getText());
                pps.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(preciotxt.getText()));
                pps.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(cantidadtxt.getText()));        
                pps.executeUpdate();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro exitoso!");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(add.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you! This was my mistake! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong setters, i.e, the code should be something like:

```
pps.setString(1, productotxt.getText());
 pps.setInt(2, preciotxt);
 pps.setInt(3, cantidadtxt);
 pps.executeUpdate();
```

convert "preciotxt" and "cantidadtxt" to integer if it is not..